# (Prove/Disprove): $G$ is a $p$-edge-connected graph, then $L(G)$ is a $(2p-2)$-edge-connected graph

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

This was a problem given to me in a basic graph theory course, and I have been stuck in this problem for a pretty long time. I am not exactly able to find a way to relate edge-connectedness of $L(G)$ with that of $G$. However, I have been able to show that the $\delta(L(G)) \ge (2p-2)$, but not been able to conclude any further.

Comment: What is $L(G)$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.